# .NET project - Only secure content is displayed - IE11

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

On the same lines as this Q:
[Only secure content is displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601467/only-secure-content-is-displayed)

I am using IE11. In my case, I can see this message/warning "Only secure content is displayed" only when I deploy the code to Production server. Same code exists on Dev and QA servers and I am not seeing the message there.

What may be the cause?

[Note: I know the solution of how to fix the issue on Production server. I want to know why the issue is happening only on Production server and not on Dev and QA servers. So, please do not consider this as a duplicate of the other Q, whose link I have already posted.]

Comment: Is your production server using https and your dev *isn't* by any chance?

Comment: Your question is a duplicate of the one you linked to.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Only secure content is displayed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601467/only-secure-content-is-displayed). The answer really is there. Simply right click View Source, and check for any appearances of "http" instead of "https."

Comment: @aquinas, No...Actually, all of them are on https. But, thanks for the reply!

Comment: @Greg Burghardt and aquinas, Actually, my Q is not the exact duplicate of the links you or I have mentioned. I know how to fix it and we have fixed it that way. I want to know the reason  why it would be happening on Production server and not on other servers (when we have the same code on all the servers).

Comment: Do you have something only enabled in production, for example including ad apis?

Comment: @aquinas is saying that your Production server might be delivering web pages over HTTPS instead of HTTP. Maybe images, JavaScript files or CSS files are being linked to as HTTP when they should be linked to using HTTPS.